# SDN lab with NETFPGA-1g card and floodlight

Tags: networking, xilinx, openflow, sdn

I'am creating an SDN lab with NETFPGA-1g card and floodlight as controller, but I can't get floodlight controller to connect with the card (Not in localhost). I gave a static ip address to the controller and typed it the netfpga. 
The controller kept sending requests with no response.
What is the problem, how can i fix this ?

Comment: Is NETFPGA-1g card Openflow-enabled?

Comment: Normally yes as in the openflow install instructions : http://archive.openflow.org/wk/index.php/CentOS_NetFPGA_Install

Comment: and in fact, on setting the datapath: /home/openflow/openflow/udatapath/ofdatapath --detach punix:/var/run/dp0.sock -d 004E46324304 -i nf2c0,nf2c1,nf2c2,nf2c3

I get this error: 

RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the packets that are being transferred, check whether the HELLO messages are there between the controller and the switch.
Furthermore, check the Floodlight logs by setting the log level to DEBUG in the log configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually came from the port used by default in Floodlight isn't 6633 but 6653.